# Can't use Jitpack dependencies

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, jitpack

Trying to use ImagePicker from Jitpack however it won't import into my code even after following the adding dependency steps.

**settings.gradle**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}
rootProject.name = "Flower Identifier v1"
include ':app'
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:Tag'
implementation 'com.github.Dhaval2404:ImagePicker:Tag'
}
```

ImagePicker not being imported correctly:
[image: image of error]

Also tried removing the repos from settings.gradle and adding it to build.gradle like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

but still having the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs of all you need to declare version of this library. Change

```
implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:Tag'
implementation 'com.github.Dhaval2404:ImagePicker:Tag'
```

to specified version tag like `implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1'`.

Then you could delete

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

form `build.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks that sorted it